# Quarkus 2.16.7.Final compatibility to Postgres 12.12

Tags: postgresql, quarkus

I am using Quarkus 2.16.7.Final, I am trying to work out which versions of Postgres it is compatible with, the version I am considering is Postgres 12.12

I had a look at the documentation but am unable to find a mention of Postgres compatibility:
https://quarkus.io/guides/datasource
https://quarkus.io/blog/quarkus-2-16-7-final-released/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Everything above Postgres 8.2 should work OTB

Quarkus `2.16.7.Final` uses `quarkus-jdbc-postgresql:2.16.7.Final`.

You can see in the compiled dependencies [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.quarkus/quarkus-jdbc-postgresql/2.16.7.Final) that this Quarkus extensions uses `org.postgresql:42.5.4` JDBC driver under the hood.

According to [official Postgres JDBC documentation](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/), this JDBC driver version should support Postgres database version **8.2** (and above).

### Edit

You should also take into account features of the database version you plan to use, check [this feature matrix](https://www.postgresql.org/about/featurematrix/) which should help you decide.